# How can I improve an answer to a locked question?

Tags: support, status-completed, edits, locked-posts, historical-lock

There is this question about getting the location from the IP address:

*[Getting the location from an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address/40022411#40022411)*

The [most recently edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40022411/2360229) has a typo in it leading to a redirect to a domain placeholder, maybe a fishy website, which could be a security issue—I don't want to upset the applecart here.

I can't either comment the answer or edit it. What's the suggested process in this case besides posting the question in meta?

The typo can be found in the code section - please note the i between *geo* and *location*:

```
script.src = 'https://geoilocation-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=callback';
```

This has to be:

```
script.src = 'https://geolocation-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=callback';
```

Comment: *"The most popular answer"* based on what? The linked answer has a score of 24 (+24/-0) and one of the answers has a score of 266 (+266/-0), and another a score of 55 (+58/-3). It's the most recently modified; but that has *nothing* to do with popularity.

Comment: Also, although that question is closed, that has little to do with the problem; it's that it's locked that you can't interact with it. If it were simply closed you could downvote the answer and move on.

Comment: @Larnu - sorry, my bad, it's the most recently edited answer. I corrected it. And yes, I mean locked, sorry for mixing the terms here.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the correction you've provided. I also put the code into a snippet.

Answer (score 7):

The reason you cannot edit that post is because the entire Q&A has been *locked*. Specifically, it has had a "historical lock" applied by a moderator because, while the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, it has accumulated answers that we consider to be of too much potential use to allow it to be deleted. See the big blue banner at the top proclaiming this?

> **Locked.** This question and its answers are [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) because the question is off-topic but has historical significance. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions.

(Of course, the question is *also* closed, but a lock is "heavier" than a close, so it trumps the close, placing a much more substantial set of restrictions on interactions with the question than if it were merely closed. Both "closed" and "locked" states continue to be displayed for reference, since they do not conflict. In fact, the closure is the reason why the question had the historical lock applied.)

Locked questions cannot be edited, except by moderators. If there's something specific that *really* needs to be edited in a locked post, you have two options:

1. **Raise a moderator flag** on the post, using the "requires moderator intervention" reason, and *clearly state* what needs to be edited and why. Note that such flags may be either actioned or declined, at the moderator's discretion.
2. **Post here on Meta** along the same lines: a clear statement of what needs to be edited and why. The advantage of posting here is that you have more characters available to make your argument for editing. It also allows the larger community to weigh in. If there's substantial community support for making an edit, it becomes much harder for a moderator to say "no". Of course, on the other hand, posting on Meta also allows a much larger number of people to say "no" if they disagree with you. :-)

*In general*, we do not edit posts with a historical lock. The whole point of the historical lock is to freeze the post as it was at that point in time. It is a value-preserving alternative to outright deletion. Posts that are historically locked are no longer maintained. So we would only edit them in exceptional conditions. Opinions may vary, but a link that has rotted and is redirecting to some unsavory content is, in my opinion, a sufficiently exceptional condition. (Although, if it is happening at a larger scale on a particular historically-locked post, then that is probably a justification to move straight to deletion.)

I've looked at [the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40022411), and I don't see any links in there that have rotted or are in any need of editing. So, this question is, unfortunately, is an example of an *unclear* request to edit a locked post.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I understand the reasons and the consequence of a locked question. I asked for the process how to proceed if I found an error. Apparently I'm missing something, but I don't see a way to inform a moderator about this issue. That's why I'm asking. The URL in question is btw: https://geoilocation-db.com/ - it has to be https://geolocation-db.com/

Comment: @n.r. You mean the one in the code snippet? I wouldn't consider that relevant, the intended functionality of the snippet is what matters, not whether or not it works by copying and pasting it. The links in the text portion are correct if a user needs them anyway.

Comment: "*If there's substantial community support for making an edit...*" => (+1) from me **for** the Edit. looks like a no-brainer, simply correcting a Typo, => from `geoilocation` to `geolocation`... (Same Typo btw also in the only Comment to that Answer...)

Comment: Given that [there's no flag option on historically locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247503/1099857) how would you suggest flagging for moderator attention?

Comment: @HenryEcker flag any post you like

Comment: @RobertLongson But there's no flag option, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @n.r flag **any** post on the site using a custom flag. You don't have to flag that particular post.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a minute to understand [the workaround @Robert Longson is suggesting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417705/how-can-i-improve-an-answer-to-a-locked-question?noredirect=1#comment907113_417706):

As a locked question has no way of interaction, you need to grab any other post on *SO* (preferably from the same section), use the flag option there, select the custom option "in need of moderator intervention" and add a reference to the locked post describing your problem.

Comment: You can flag your _own_ posts.